# Firefox: Remove all files from cache except images

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, browser-cache, firefox-quantum

When the Firefox browser closes, I have configured it to clear everything except cache so that images load quickly on the next run.

However when I checked C:\Users\jacobgu\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\gcpomq43.default\cache2  I saw that it contained .js and some other files as well.

Is there any way (or Addon) where I can auto-configure Firefox to store only images in my cache and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with blocking non-image file-types from the cache,
but O can help with the question in the title.

> Firefox: Remove all files from cache except images

To answer this question, try to download and install the free
[NirSoft MZCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html)
that can manage the cache files.

[image]

Start it and
click on the "Content Type" column to sort, select all files except images,
and then use <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete the selected files.

Comment: Thanks. In my question I had asked how to auto-configure Firefox. Is there a way I can configure this plugin (say via a batch script) so that it deletes all the files except image files.

Comment: I don't think so.